# VS 2012 crashing on start

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2012 crashing on start. I assume, it may be as a result of uninstallation of DevX Expression uninstallation which was done through Add/Remove features & Vs still trying to load add-in. Is it?

However I tried removing VS cache file and run devenv/resetsettings and tried VS repair option from Add/Remove featuresbut didn't work. I also tried VS repair option from Add/Remove features Is there any solution to fix the error?

I see two entries in Event Viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTask.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate.StartPage.ServiceProviderExtensions+<SatisfyImportsOnceAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate.StartPage.StartPageVideosGridViewHost+<InitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate.StartPage.TaskCancellationHelper+<FireAndForget>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

2. Application error
   Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23418, time stamp: 0x5708a7e4
   Exception code: 0xe0434352
   Fault offset: 0x0000c54f
   Faulting process id: 0x4f4
   Faulting application start time: 0x01d28768d5a8d4ef
   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
   Report Id: 1ab9efde-f35c-11e6-ac49-ecf4bb5b8a80

Comment: create a crash dump: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx and analyze it with windbg by running **!analyze -v**

Comment: Google "clear mef component cache".  If that doesn't help then ask DevExpress for assistance.  If that doesn't help then repair/reinstall.  if that doesn't help then wipe the machine.  If that doesn't help then use another machine.